# div to cover entire area of image only

Tags: css

I made an image that when hovered upon will change the opacity of the div on top of it. The div should be the same size as the image. I have managed to place the div on top of the image. However, when I set the width and height to 100%, the div covered the image INCLUDING the image's margin. I want to know how to fix it so that the div can only cover the image with the margin not included. Please note that I need the image to be responsive, so I do not want to set the height in pixels as much as possible.

Here's the fiddle: 
    https://jsfiddle.net/gsuxlzt/77vn1uyg/

Here's the code:

```css
.margin {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.photo-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}
.photo-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cbe1f4;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #18121e;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.photo-title:hover {
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-thumbnail">
  <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail margin photo-thumbnail" src="http://i36.photobucket.com/albums/e20/kingjami/photo-frame_zpsljshbjdq.jpg" />
  <a href=#>
    <div class="photo-title">
      <h2 style="padding: 20% 0 20% 0;">Project Title</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue comes from the fact that the parent div expands by 10 px following the img's margin. Are you sure you don't want to apply the margin-bottom on the parent div rather than the img?

Comment: I did put the margin on the parent div as you and Lucian pointed out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

Html Code:

```
<div class="photo-thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail margin photo-thumbnail" src="http://i36.photobucket.com/albums/e20/kingjami/photo-frame_zpsljshbjdq.jpg"/><a href=#>
        <div class="photo-title">
          <h2 style="padding: 20% 0 20% 0;">Project Title</h2>
        </div>
          </a>
```

CSS Code:-

```
.margin {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.img-thumbnail{padding:0px;}
.photo-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}

.photo-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cbe1f4;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #18121e;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.photo-title:hover {
  opacity: .9;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dhavalr/77vn1uyg/8/

Answer (score 0):

first of all, don't use padding and margin for `<img>` instead use it for `.photo-thumbnail`

and use this code.

```
.photo-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

using inline-block for the parent can make image flexible as well as only occupy the necessary area as image.

try this, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. It worked as soon as I moved the margin to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

- In your example you are missing the closing  of your "photo-thumbnail"
- You are not obligated to use "Width: 100%", "Height: 100%", when you have an absolutely positioned element, instead you can make it take all of the space with

```
 

    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
```

And in your case you can set the

```
bottom: 10px;
```

since that is how much your div gets out of the picture

here is an example in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77vn1uyg/3/